# Proof of Kolmogorov's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

[image]

I am having troubles at the final line of the image, could somone explain how they replaced the union with the maximum?

Comment: One of the terms is $\geq \frac{1}{k}$ if and only if the maximum is.

Comment: Yes I agree, but why does that mean the probability is the same?

Comment: Because the events are the same.

Comment: I don't see how the events are the same

Comment: What is Theorem 4.7 in this case? It looks related to Markov's Inequality. It's a very interesting proof so far but I'd be even more interested to see how it finishes, and how it uses the independence. I can't find the source online.